# Rechartsで軸のラベルを小数からパーセントに変換するには？

Tags: javascript

以下のサイトを参照しながらコードを書いています。

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-lehmann-82dzz?file=/src/dashboardView.js:1404-1406 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43978473/recharts-normalised-stacked-bar-charts

半分は成功しましたが、添付した画像のように、横軸の単位が小数となってしまいます。パーセントに変換して表示したいのですが、どのような方法があるでしょうか。

```
<XAxis 
        type="number"
        domain={['data * 100', 'data * 100 ']}
</XAxis>
```

現在、XAxisは上記のように書いています。

[image]

Answer (score 2):

以下の記述で行うことが出来ました！

```
tickFormatter={(tick) => {
    return `${tick*100}%`;
}}
```